# MongoDB Aggregation to conditionally update usernames in all of the collection with large number of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

We have a `userLogin` collection with large number of documents in Mongo Atlas. I’ve to write an aggregation to lowercase the `username` field if the field is not in lowercase. The collection has large number of documents (north of 500,000).

I've written the following aggregate function, which does lowercase the field, if the field has any character that is not in lowercase. I'm checking with `$match` if the value in username field and its lowercase value are not equal, in that case, using `$set` I'm setting the field with lowercase value of it.

```
await userLogin.aggregate([
    
      {
        '$match': {
          '$expr': {
            '$ne': [
              '$username', {
                '$toLower': '$username'
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$set': {
          'username': {
            '$toLower': '$username'
          }
        }
      }
    ,
    {
      $out: 'userLogin',
    },
  ]);
```

It works fine for documents with usernames that have uppercase characters in it. However, if the username is already in lowercase, document gets deleted. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Since username has a unique index on it, in case when a document with lowercase username already exist in the collection, document currently under processing (username getting lowercased) should be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The `$match` condition in your case, is filtering out the documents, which are already in `lowercase`, it's unnecessary. Simply this should suffice:

```
await userLogin.aggregate([
     {
        '$set': {
          'username': {
            '$toLower': '$username'
          }
        }
      }
    ,
    {
      $out: 'userLogin',
    },
  ])
```

This will set the `username`, regardless of whether it has uppercase characters or not.

Also `$out`, replaces the collection completely, that's why the documents seem to be deleted, when ran with `$match`. Either remove `$match`, or use `$merge` stage instead of `$out`.

Here's the link to `$merge` [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/).

It should be something like this:

```
await userLogin.aggregate([
    
      {
        '$match': {
          '$expr': {
            '$ne': [
              '$username', {
                '$toLower': '$username'
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$set': {
          'username': {
            '$toLower': '$username'
          }
        }
      }
    ,
    {
      $merge:  { 
        into: "userLogin", 
        on: "_id", 
        whenMatched: "replace"
       },
    },
   ]);
```

Comment: This makes sense. Also, what is a good way to check if the 'to be' lowercase value already exist in the collection? I want to skip that document, if the lowercase already exist.

Comment: Since you are writing to a new collection, skipping the document will result in that document, not getting written to the collection. That's why I am suggesting using `$merge`, it replaces the  matching document, keep the non-matching one as well

Comment: Right, but since, I'll be writing in the same collection, there is a chance that another document might exist in the collection that has the same username (in all lowercase), and usernames have to be unique, so it will fail. Isn't it?

Comment: Replace the documents on the basis of their `_id`, I have updated the answer to demonstrate that

Comment: `username` is indexed and failing in this case: `MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: E11000 duplicate key error collection: materialRequest.userLogin index: username_1 dup key: { username: "jack.clinton" }`

Comment: What is expected in the case of more than one users having the same username?

Comment: In case, if lowercasing the username results in a duplicate/collision, it shouldn't be lowercased and skipped.

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest you to store lowercased name because if two users have name, say, `Clint` and `cLint`, after lowercasing them, they will still be the same